# How to prove $\sin(kx)$, $\cos(kx)$ equality?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove this equality please? [equality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALc6s.jpg)

Edit: MathJax version:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin (kx)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)\sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos (kx)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)\cos\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
$$

Comment: If you don't like Euler's formula, by induction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The left-hand sides are respectively the imaginary and real parts of the partial sum of the geometric series
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm e^{ikx}=\frac{-1}{e^{ix}-1}.$$
Factor out $\;\mathrm e^{i\tfrac{(n+1)x}2}$ in the numerator,$\;\mathrm e^{i\tfrac{x}2}$ from the denominator, and use *Euler's formulæ*:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm e^{ikx}&=\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i(n+1)x}2}}{\mathrm e^{i\tfrac{x}2}}\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i(n+1)x}2}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i(n+1)x}2}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{ix}2}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{ix}2}}=\mathrm e^{i\tfrac{nx}2}\frac{2i\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}2}{2i\sin\dfrac x2}\\\
&=\Bigl(\cos\frac{nx}2+i\sin\frac{nx}2\Bigr)\frac{\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}2}{\sin\dfrac x2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand why the sum is equal the fraction?

Comment: It's the high-school formula $\;1+z+\dots+z^n=\dfrac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$ which is valid for all $z\ne 1$, with $\;z=\mathrm e^{ix}$.

Comment: Thank you, and how the proof continue? I am sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: @Elisabeth: I've added the details.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: multiply by $$\frac{\sin \frac x2}{\sin \frac x2}$$ then use product to sum formulas
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin kx=\sin x +\sin 2x +...+\sin nx\\\to 
\frac{\sin \frac x2}{\sin \frac x2}\times (\sin x +\sin 2x +...+\sin nx)$$